# What is wrong with these lines?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, authentication, tkinter

I have the following lines in a large program.

```
username = Entry(loginPage)
password = Entry(loginPage)

button1 = Button(loginPage,text = "Login", fg = "red", command = loginClicked(username.get(),password.get()))
```

When the program is run, the function `loginClicked` runs once at the start (when the fields are empty and the button hasn't been clicked) and that is the only time it runs. After, when the button is clicked the function doesn't run at all. A print statement in the function confirms this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, when you create the widget you are calling ('running') the function before the widget is created, instead of passing the function handle (may be wrong terminology here) to the widget option `command=`.

This can be solved by using anonymous functions with `lambda`:

```
button1 = Button(root,text = "Login",
                 fg = "red", 
                 command = lambda: loginClicked(username.get(), password.get()))
```

This creates a 'throw-away' function to feed into Tkinter's callback, which calls your function `loginClicked()` with its correct arguments.

You can also read [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) for more information on Tkinter callbacks